# Moving to USA or UK with family, while keeping my job on my home country

Tags: resident-permit

I work at an oil company on a rotational basis; 4 weeks on and 4 weeks off. I intend to move with my family to the USA or UK to allow my kids to get a better education. But I would like to continue working in the oil industry in my home country. Only going to USA during my time off. Is this possible? What I need to do?

Comment: What nationalities do you hold?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any existing connections to the US, such as family there? If not, this is going to be extremely difficult or impossible.

If you're only going to the US on your time off, and not working, you might be able to make the case for this being tourism: it's OK to go to the US a lot as a tourist, as long as you're not living there.

If you want to have your family live there, and your kids to attend school, then they'll all need some kind of legal, non-visitor status in the US: you [can't do this as 'tourist'](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html).

The only (common) ways to get this are employment-based (you, or perhaps your spouse, could try to get a skilled job in the US which would qualify for an [H-1B visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa)), or [family-base](https://www.uscis.gov/greencard/family-preference)d (if you already have close relatives there).

If neither of these work out, a final option is the [Diversity Visa program](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/diversity-visa-program-entry.html), essentially a lottery for US permanent residency. The odds are poor, and some countries aren't eligible, but it's free to apply and there's no harm in trying.

Comment: For completeness, if the OP's wife has $500,000 available for investment in a business in certain areas, she could try for an EB-5 visa.